# How do I restore the default ruby configuration on my mac running os x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, default, restore

I'm learning ruby and I had an advanced developer working with me. He installed a bunch of gemsets and adjusted configurations and I need to know how to remove it all and start from scratch so that I can follow along with tutorials. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like he's installed rvm since you're referring to gemsets? If so, you can simply delete the entire ~/.rvm folder and it should switch back to using system ruby.